# How to represent R function dexp mathematically?

Tags: statistics, math-software, mathematical-modeling

I need help representing this line of code mathematically.

```
exp(sum(dexp(x,prop_theta,log=TRUE)) - sum(dexp(x,cur_theta,log=TRUE)))
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: ... what does this have to do with regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

In R, `dexp` is the density of exponential distribution, $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. Here $\lambda$ is the second argument of `dexp`, which is the  named `prop_theta` in first instance, and `cur_theta` in the second. But the parameter `log=TRUE` tells R to return the *logarithm* of density function. That is $\log( \lambda e^{-\lambda x})$, which simplifies to  $\log(\lambda)-\lambda x$.

Assuming that $x$ holds a list of numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, what you have is
$$
\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\log(p_\theta) - p_\theta x_i )-\sum_{i=1}^n (\log(c_\theta) - c_\theta x_i )
\right)
$$
where I replaced `prop` and `cur` with one-letter names. Looks more "mathematical" this way.

Comment: Awesome, thanks 9000 sit-ups everyday.